# How do you test for NotFound() in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi I am trying to write Unit Tests for my controller, this is my fist test I have written, well, trying to write.

In my controller I have the method -

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var centre = _centreRepository.GetCentreById(id);

    if (centre == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return View(Centre);
}
```

I am trying to write a test so that it passes when NotFound() is returned.

For my test I have -

```
 [Test]
 public void TestVaccinationCentreDetailsView()
 {
     var centrerepository = new Mock<ICentreRepository>();

     var controller = new CentreController(centrerepository.Object);

      var result = controller.Details(99);
      Assert.AreEqual(404, result.StatusCode);
}
```

When run result returns Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult object, which has status code of 404.
result.StatusCode does not exist.

I am confused.

I am using .Net 5, ASP.Net core MVC 5.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you check whether it is of type `NotFoundResult`?

Comment: How do you do that.  Assert.IsTypeOf<> doesn't exist when I try?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isinstanceoftype?view=mstest-net-1.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller action is returning an abstraction. ie `IActionResult`

Cast the result in the test to the expected type and assert on that

```
[Test]
public void TestVaccinationCentreDetailsView() {
    //Arrange
    var centrerepository = new Mock<ICentreRepository>();

    var controller = new CentreController(centrerepository.Object);

    //Act
    var result = controller.Details(99) as NotFoundResult; //<-- CAST HERE

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(404, result.StatusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to just test if the `result` is of `NotFoundResult` type

```
var result = controller.Details(99);

//I prefer this one
Assert.IsInstanceOf<NotFoundResult>(result);
//other possible solution
Assert.IsTrue(result is NotFoundResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried verifying or casting to type `NotFoundResult` and `NotFoundObjectResult` but was still getting `null`.  The result I was getting was of type `StatusCodeResult`, but I did need to cast to that in order to make an assertion.  The final result was this:

```
[Fact]
public async void TestGetStuffNotFound()
{
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.GetStuff()).ReturnsAsync(new List<Stuff>());
    var result = await controller.GetAllStuff(mockContext.Object) as StatusCodeResult;
    Assert.Equal(404, result?.StatusCode);
}
```